# Homestead server times out when route not found

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

Accessing any invalid/non existing route on fresh laravel app returns halts & timeout after 60 seconds.

Error: The process "git status -s" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

Same code works fine fine locally on xampp and returns method/controller not found within a couple of seconds. Please guide.

P.S: Seems like git status takes a lot of time inside vagrant ssh, but it works fine on host machine. What also bothers me is why git status command is being run when accessing route?

- Host: Windows 10
- Box: v9.2.0.
- Virtualbox v6.1.2
- Vagrant: v2.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so turns out the laravel error page package `ignition` is causing all the problems.
There is an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/179) on there github page and multiple solution including the git status issue.